# Capturing content which can start with Parser keywords in Xtext

Tags: grammar, xtext

The following is the simplified version of my actual grammar :-

```
grammar org.hello.World 

import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore

generate world "http://www.hello.org/World"

Model:
    content=AnyContent greetings+=Greeting*;

AnyContent:
    (ID | ANY_OTHER)*
;

Greeting:
    '<hello>' name=ID '</hello>';

terminal ID:
    ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+
;

terminal ANY_OTHER:
    .
;
```

So using above grammar if my input is like :-

**<hi><hello>world</hello>**

Then I am getting an syntax error saying that **mismatched character 'i' expecting 'e'** at Column 2 .

My requirement is that AnyContent should match "<hi>" , can anyone guide me about how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it with Xtext. I advice you to split your problem. You first problem is syntaxic, you need to parser your file. The second problem is semantic, you want to give a "sense" to your objets and tell who is the container. Define the container and the containment for XML can't be done inside your grammar.

1. Make a custom Ecore and make an easy grammar, with start and end tag. You don't really care about the name of your tag.
   Example :

   ```
   Model returns XmlFile: (StartTag|EndTag|Text)+;

   Text returns Text: text=STRING;

   StartTag returns StartTag: '<' name=ID '>';

   EndTag returns EndTag: '</' name=ID '>';
   ```
2. Change the TokenSource. The token source will give the token to your Parser. You can override the nature of your token, merge or split them. 
   The idea here is to merge all token outside the between of  `">"` and `"</"`. 
   This token represent a Text, so you can create a single token for all elements containing between this elements. Example :

   ```
   class CustomTokenSource extends XtextTokenStream{


   new(TokenSource tokenSource, ITokenDefProvider tokenDefProvider) {  
       super(tokenSource,tokenDefProvider)
   }

   override LT(int k) {
       var Token token = super.LT(k)
       if(token != null && token.text != null) token.tokenOverride(k);
       token
   }
   ```

In this example you need to add your custom code on the method "tokenOverride".

Add your custom token source on your parser :

```
class XDSLParser extends DSLParser{

override protected XtextTokenStream createTokenStream(TokenSource tokenSource) {
   return new CustomTokenSource(tokenSource, getTokenDefProvider());
}

}
```

3. Compute the containement : the containment of your elements can be compute after the parsing. After it, you can get your model and change it as you will. To make it, you need to override the method "doParse" of your Parser "XDSLParser" as follow :

   ```
   override protected IParseResult doParse(String ruleName, CharStream in,         NodeModelBuilder nodeModelBuilder, int initialLookAhead) {      
   var IParseResult result = super.doParse( ruleName,  in,  nodeModelBuilder,  initialLookAhead)

   //Give you model        
   result.rootASTElement;

       return result
   ```

   }

Note : The model that you obtain after the parsing will be flat. The xmlFile Object will contain all the elements in the good order. You need to write an algorithm to build the containement on your AST model.

Answer (score 0):

This will require a lot of tweaking in the grammar due to the nature of the antlr lexer that is used by Xtext. The lexer will not roll back for the keyword `<hello>`: As soon as it sees a `<` followed by an `h` it'll try consume the hello-token. Something along these lines could work though:

```
Model:
    content=AnyContent greetings+=Greeting*;

AnyContent:
    (ID | ANY_OTHER | '<' (ID | ANY_OTHER | '/' | '>') | '/' | '>' | 'hello')*
;

Greeting:
    '<' 'hello '>' name=ID '<' '/' 'hello' '>';

terminal ID:
    ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+
;

terminal ANY_OTHER:
    .
;
```

The approach won't scale for real world grammars but maybe it helps to get on the some working track.

Comment: That was a useful information for me. So if I am planning to achieve this via Lexer then overriding mTokens() would suffice my requirement ? . Can you point me to any such link where similar kind of problem is solved (to get a rough idea.)

Comment: By the way ... is it possible to make any other html tags to be matched inside "Greeting" parser rule. i.e.**name=ID** can also be AnyContent.

Comment: If you really want to parse XML, I strongly recommend to use an XML parser for that.